# Proof of $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \| x_n - x \| = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis

So it was stated to me in another topic that the following is true:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \| x_n - x \| = 0.$

Can anyone provide a proof (or link to) a proof of this? I cannot seem to be able to find this result in any of my books, or online.

Comment: The assertion holds (on a normed space) only if $x=0$.

Comment: You might have meant "$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \| x_n - x \| = 0$". If so, that's just a definition.

Comment: I am going to assume that you are correct @JimmyK4542, would you have the proof for that?

Comment: Why not ask this as a comment [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/918984/)? This is what comments are made for.

Comment: Because it is still a stand alone question?

Comment: Is it? [I doubt that](http://youtu.be/JRLNdcmRcFY?t=0m30s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely a definition. Let $\varepsilon>0$. If $$\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=x$$ we have that
$$\|x_n-x\|<\varepsilon$$
if $n\geq N$ for a certain $N\in\mathbb N$. Consequently,

$$\big|\|x_n-x\|-0\big|<\varepsilon $$
if $n\geq N$ and so $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\|x_n-x\|=0.$$

Comment: "It's not entirely a definition" How do you define $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$ then?

Comment: I agree that it is a definition.